# jQuery - .getjson VS .ajax json

Tags: jquery, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference Between $.getJSON() and $.ajax() in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076013/difference-between-getjson-and-ajax-in-jquery)

super simple question.... between .getjson and .ajax() json which is faster?

considering retrieving and parsing data.

Much thanks.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`.getjson()` calls `.ajax()`, so they should be equivalent.

Comment: Not entirely correct. `.getJSON()` parses the JSON string into an Object, whereas `.ajax()` returns a String that you would have to parse as in `obj=jQuery.parseJSON(data)`

Comment: @Apuleius not necessarily,IMHO if you specify "dataType: json" the returned data will be parsed into Object automagically.

Comment: looks like .getJson caches by default and doesn't have a direct cache true/false option like .ajax. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13391563/how-to-set-cache-false-for-getjson-in-jquery

Answer (score 41):

Same thing. [`getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) is a shorthand for `.ajax(..)` with specific parameters.

To quote the documentation of `.getJSON()`:

> This is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to:
>
> ```
>    $.ajax({
>       url: url,
>       dataType: 'json',
>       data: data,
>       success: callback
>     });
> ```

Answer (score 13):

I had a similiar question, and wanted to point out the following documentation in [JQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> The $.ajax() function underlies all
>   Ajax requests sent by jQuery. **It is
>   often unnecessary to directly call
>   this function**, as several higher-level
>   alternatives like $.get() and .load()
>   are available and are easier to use.
>   If less common options are required,
>   though, $.ajax() can be used more
>   flexibly.

Answer (score 5):

[`jQuery.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) uses the same [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call finally, so there are no speed differences.