# JQuery getJson method returns cached data for the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `getJson` method to get data from the URL and load the grid but `getJson` function returns cached data.

I tried using `$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });` but that did not help.

Comment: might be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13391563/how-to-set-cache-false-for-getjson-in-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" }
});
```