# how to make my button fire as if it is the first time it has been cliked

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, onclick

I am working on project where I am trying to generate quote form api. Here is my syntax,

```
$("#btn").on("click",function(){
    $.getJSON("https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1",function(a){
   $("#display").append(a[0].content);
    })
 })
```

the problem I am facing is that I am not getting a new json return each time I am clicking the button, instead the same quote is generated. How can I fix that?

Comment: Inspect the response in your dev tools. Is it returning the same JSON each time? Is the browser caching it?

Comment: @Damon, could you please give me more insight on how to go about it?

Comment: What browser are you on? In most modern browsers you can right click - "Inspect" - and find a Network tab. Make your ajax request, and a new entry will show up with the request and response. What status code are you getting from the server? Is the response the same or different? If you are getting the same response each time and the status code is 200 (not cached), the problem is with the request itself (wrong syntax to get a random quote) or with the API itself.

Comment: Also, I just tried logging this request 3 times in my console (with no modifications) and it was different each time. jQuery automatically cache busts it so that wasn't a problem.

Comment: @Damon I am using google chrome. I just checked the network tab. Each time I am making request a new row is listed on the network tab. Its status code is 200(of course) and I hovered over size and it says from disk cache

Comment: Is there a cache buster param at the end of your Request URL? It would look something like `&_=1497109274251`. jQuery should do this automatically.

Comment: not really. The url at the network tab is just this  'posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1'

Comment: can you post the exact URL under Headers > General > Request URL

Comment: @Damon thank you so much for all the support. I finally found myself way to set the caching false.

Comment: np, glad you figured it out. If caching was turned on, @nerestaren 's solution should have worked.

Answer (score 0):

That may be because your browser is caching the response.

I suggest you to add a timestamp to your request as a parameter, like

```
$.getJSON("https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&t=" + new Date());
```

You can also check this question: [How to set cache false for getJSON in JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13391563/how-to-set-cache-false-for-getjson-in-jquery).

Comment: Are you sure? [Your code](https://jsfiddle.net/fruh5ca7/) vs [my suggestion](https://jsfiddle.net/fruh5ca7/1/).

Comment: Thank you very. You are right. I set the cache false for getJSON directly and it worked