# JQuery $.getJSON with username and password basic authentication?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, getjson

I want something like this: [How to use Basic Auth with jQuery and AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507234/how-to-use-basic-auth-and-jquery-and-ajax)

In the question there they explained how to use authentication

I need to use a jQuery `$.getJSON` instead of a `$.ajax` request to a server because it doesn't support cross-site.
And also I need to submit a user and a password. 
**Is there a way to submit a user and password as parameters in a `$.getJSON` WITHOUT sending it in the URL like `https://user:password@myserver.com`?**

Comment: `$.ajax` doesn't support CORS when you use JSONP, it uses JSONP instead of CORS. If you want to make a cross-origin request then the server needs to give you permission with CORS or hack around the same origin policy with JSONP. If you use JSONP you can't set arbitrary HTTP headers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass request headers in a jQuery AJAX GET call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258645/pass-request-headers-in-a-jquery-ajax-get-call)

Answer (score -1):

$.getJSON is a shorthand for $.ajax, so indeed you probably need ajax. You can see on http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ how to set **headers**

```
$.ajax(url, {crossDomain:true, headers:{'X-My':'Foo'}})
```

And this is possible duplicate of [Pass request headers in a jQuery AJAX GET call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258645/pass-request-headers-in-a-jquery-ajax-get-call)

Comment: It won't support a cross-origin request so I need to use $.getJSON. With $.Ajax I would know how to use it

Comment: as I told you already getJSON calls ajax, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922175/jquery-getjson-vs-ajax-json

Comment: @DennisKonoppa — See my comment on the original question. You appear to be confusing the `getJSON` function with JSONP and the idea of cross-origin requests with CORS.

Comment: Setting `crossDomain:true` is usually pointless. It only matters if you are making an XMLHttpRequest (i.e. not JSONP) request to the **same** origin and then performing an *HTTP redirect* to a different origin.

Answer (score -1):

```
$.getJSON("url", { user: "name", password: "123456" })
    .done(function(json) {
        console.log("Store User autthentication successfully");
    })
    .fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
    });
```