# .getJSON only works on Flask Dev not IIS 8 when there is an html tag in value

Tags: javascript, python, iis, flask, getjson

I have the following client-side JavaScript code that works just fine when using python-Flask Dev server, irrespective what type of content $('#b_comment_selected').text() has. Here is the JS code.

```
function some_editing(){
$.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + "/_edit_me", 
{
content: $('#b_comment_selected').text(),
label: $('#b_label_selected' ).text() 
},
function () { //do something}
)
}
```

It also works when I run it on IIS and $('#b_comment_selected').text() does not contain any html tags. But the code does not work when there are html tags in $('#b_comment_selected').text(). The error I get in Chrome's console is a 403 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden)

My questions are: 
why does it work in the flask dev environment?
Why does it not work on IIS?
And how to fix it?

If I had to guess it has to do with characters like < or > but I can't find a definitive answer to my set of questions.

Comment: You're probably seeing ASP.Net's request filtering. http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, will look into the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the Solution was to replace the getJSON method with the ajax method, and this answered my third question "how to fix it?". And I think the first comment to the accepted answer in here [jQuery - .getjson VS .ajax json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922175/jquery-getjson-vs-ajax-json) 
answers my first and second question, in the context of securities in place on IIS, but then again I am not hundred percent sure.