# Parse JSON data from url

Tags: ajax, json, parsing, getjson

I have JSON data in following format:

```
parent: {
       child: {
             sample:[
                     {
                      key:value,
                      key:value,
                     }
                     {
                      key:value,
                      key:value,
                     }
                     {
                      key:value,
                      key:value,
                     }
                    ] 
                 }
            }
```

How should i parse this data using jquery? using $ ajax or getJSON? Which is preferable method? Please Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need only json data the you can use getJSON.However both are equivalent as getJSON is short hand for $.ajax.More you can read this :
[Difference Between $.getJSON() and $.ajax() in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076013/difference-between-getjson-and-ajax-in-jquery#)
In my script:

```
$.getJSON('test.php',{ val:"test" }, function (data) {
     $.each(data, function (i, v) {
               //do your work here with each value returned from server side.
     });
});
```

In my test.php file:

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="GET"&&$_REQUEST['val']=="test")
{
    header("Content-type: application/json");
    $a1 = array(  'answer1' => 'a', 'score1'=>3, 'answer2' => 'b', 'score2'=>5);
    echo json_encode($a1);
    die();
}
```

You will receive an object containing :{"answer":"a","score":3,"answer1":"b","score1":5}

**if you are working with aspx page then you must use $.ajax as there is an option for content header which must be "application/json" OTHERWISE asp.net will reject the request**

Example:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "Demo.aspx/Demo_Method",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
            dataType: "JSON",
            type: "GET",
            success: function (response) {
                alert('Success' + response);
            }
        });
```

in my aspx page:

```
    [WebMethod()]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)] 
    public static string Demo_Method()
    {
        return "test";
    }
```

As you mentioned in your Question.Your data seems to be incorrect.Correct Json Format should be like this:

```
 parent: { 
     child: { 
          sample: [
                   { key: "1", value: "value1" }, 
                   { key: "2", value: "value2" }, 
                   { key: "3", value: "value3" }
                  ]
            }
         }
```

If you received a response as in above format then you can simply access this like:

```
 var response= { parent: { child: { sample: [{ key: "1", value: "value1" }, { key: "2", value: "value2" }, { key: 3, value: "value3"}]}} };

 var samples_arr=response.parent.child.sample;  //create a sample Array.


 $.each(samples_arr,function(){
      alert(v.key+" and "+ v.value); // access here your each element
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Can you please give some sample for getJSON?

Comment: Ok I am editing my answer and putting an example here using php.Please check

Comment: I dont know php. I want to do the task using jqury.

Comment: I dont know php. I want to do the task using jqury. I have aspx page which contains the JSON data.

Comment: but you need some server side code where $.getJSON will send request.Jquery is client side. getJSON as name suggests Getting JSON data from the Server.

Comment: I have a certain URL of aspx page. That page contains JSON data. I have to parse it.

Comment: ok it means your server page is .aspx.Ok wait i'll come with another example of aspx.

Comment: plz check response in firebug it will be {'d':'test'} so try alert(response.d);

Comment: Sorry but i didnt get you.Can you please explain?

Comment: i mean to say try this: success: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            } in the success of ajax call.Also plz confirm your aspx method contains all code as shown.[webMethod] and  [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]

Comment: d is the key returned in object.that is why i am referring here response.d

Comment: I am getting response as i have mentioned in my original question..what should i do in that case?

Comment: If you are receiving data like {'key':'value'} then simpley you can use it like response.key.If there is some other format then you can use JSON.parse(response) to make a simple object.More you can refer http://www.json.org/js.html and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc836466%28v=vs.94%29.aspx

Comment: Yes i am getting data in {'key':'value'}. But in format i mentioned above.

Comment: I am updating my answer  please check.

Comment: Thanks for valuable help. I will try it.

Comment: I am getting error in chrome: XMLHttpRequest cannot load URL. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
In firefox i am getting blank response.