# Cannot load data from local JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

```
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src= "C:\Documents and Settings\vivek.aggarwal\My Documents\Downloads\jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
  <script src="mydata.json"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="demo"> ABC </p>
    <script>

    $.getJSON(mydata.json, function(data) {
        var output = data.login[0].one;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML= output;
    });

    </script>
</body>
```

and this is my JSON file (mydata.json)

```
{
    "login": [
        {
            "one": "vivek"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I'd start by quoting the URI, ie `$.getJSON('mydata.json', ...`. Of course, your console would have alerted you to this error, if you'd bothered to check it

Comment: Get rid of the duplicate jQuery script tags (`c:\documents....`) and change `$.getJSON('mydata.json'...)` Note the quotes. Please learn to use developer toolbar (press F12 in Chrome)

Comment: ... also, don't include `mydata.json` via a `<script>` tag

Comment: and while you're using jQuery anyway... `$('#demo').html(data.login[0].one)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this method, it works for me.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'mydata.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result) {
       //Your code here, result is json obj
       $('#demo').html(result.login[0].one);
    },
    error: function() {
      // alert("error");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thnx Phil, i replaced with jQuery for assignment.

Comment: What's the reason for steering away from `$.getJSON`?

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076013/difference-between-getjson-and-ajax-in-jquery

Comment: For short answer to steering away,

.getjson() calls .ajax().

Comment: Yes, I know they're equivalent. That's why I asked

Comment: They are equi, thats true but .getjson() calls .ajax(), so better to use .ajax().  And one more reason that you can modify with ease.

Comment: No its not running....showing errors

(1)Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : mydata.json:2

(2)XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///D:/vivek/vivlogin/prac/mydata.json. Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. loginprac.html:1

Please help me

Comment: Update your current code in question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it should work.

```
$.getJSON("mydata.json", function(data) { 
        var output = data.login[0].one;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML= output;
});
```