# Pass Javascript array with Jquery and JSON from client-side to server side in Flask

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, json, flask

I am attempting to pass a Javascript Array from the client side to the server side (Flask). My code seems to work for both integers and strings. When I try to send an array with the exact same code, I get `None`.

Server side code:

```
@app.route("/route1", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def route1():

    a = request.args.get('post')
    result = json.dumps(a)
    print(a)
    print(result)
```

Client side:

```
$SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root | tojson | safe }};

var x = ["test", "test2"];

function newFunction() {

    console.log(x)
    $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/route1', { post: x },
        function (data) {
            var response = data.result;
            console.log(response);
        }

    )
};
```

As I said before, this seems to work perfectly when `x` is simply assigned a string or an integer. When trying to pass through this array, I get `None` and `NULL` for my two print statements, respectively. How can I properly pass through the array to the server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I wasn't able to get this to work using `$.getJSON` either...

Here's a tested `$.ajax` solution:

```
    <script>
    $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root | tojson | safe }};
    var x = ["test", "test2"];
        function f1(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: $SCRIPT_ROOT + "/route1",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "JSON",
                data: JSON.stringify(x)
            });
        };
    </script>
```

I trigger this with a button like this:

```
    <button id="testing" name="testing" onclick="f1();">testing</button>
```

And the Flask code:

```
@bp.route("/route1", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def route1():
    a = request.get_json()
    print(a)
    return "hello, world"
```

Comment: This looks good, but for some reason nothing seems to be happen. I think the function isn't being triggered. Does the button need to be part of a specific form group?

Comment: I didn't put the button in a form group it's all by itself. I'm going to sleep soon, but I'll check back tomorrow to see if I can help further.

Comment: Could I name the function and trigger the function in the typical way as I've done with my original code? I am not familiar with Jquery unfortunately, but it seems to be more convoluted in terms of executing functions.

Comment: @find_all: I changed it to use plain Javascript. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately now I'm getting `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`. If you don't have the time to help me anymore that's fine, I'll just pull in the messy data I got from getlist and regex/tokenize I guess. Seems like my only option at this point unless you have an idea about this error.

Answer (score 1):

you can try below code. it will work. as you are passing array as parameter. as request.args is a MultiDict instance

```
request.args.getlist(Key)
```

Or you should try to convert your Array to Json and pass json to Server.
You can use below method to convert json

```
JSON.stringify()
```

Server side you can use

```
data = request.get_json()
```

Comment: This gave me an empty list `[]` instead of `None`

Comment: you can refer below link https://stackoverflow.com/a/23889195/1079086

Comment: I was able to get it working so I will upvote you. Unfortunately it still passes over very strangely, I get `['["test","test3"]']`. Do you know why it is in an embedded list like that?

Comment: Are you trying `request.args.getlist("post[]")` ?

Comment: Yes I tried that, and I get an empty list. Apparently I need to use AJAX though, and trying to figure out how to apply that to my current code. Would it be `$.ajax.getJSON`

Comment: yes, it will be `$.ajax({ Parameters });` kindly refer this link for more details https://stackoverflow.com/a/34807017/1079086